# Fetching image from Supabase storage through database table returns undefined URL

Tags: image, next.js, fetch, supabase, fetching-strategy

I am building an app in `Next.js`, which fetches dynamic data from a `Supabase` table. The table (called `product`) has several data points (title, description, image). My table in Supabase looks like this:
[image]

My problem is that both the description and the title are being pulled in dynamically, populating my home page properly. What is failing is the image. Images are stored in a public bucket that looks like this:

[image]

The way I'm attempting to pull the image in dynamically is as follows:

```js
import { supabase } from "../utils/supabase";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useUser } from "../context/user";
import Image from "next/dist/client/image";

export default function Home({ products, tile_url }) {
  const { user } = useUser();

  const {data:image_url} = supabase.storage.from("games").getPublicUrl(tile_url);
  console.log(image_url.publicURL);

  return (
    <div className="body w-full h-screen py-16">
      <div className="w-full max-w-3xl mx-auto px-2">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Link
            key={product.id}
            href={`/${product.id}`}
          >
            <a className="p-8 h-40 mb-4 rounded element text-xl flex">
             
              <img src={image_url.publicURL} alt="" />
              {product.title}
            </a>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const { data: products } = await supabase.from("product").select("*");

  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
};
```

The image is not returned in the frontend. The console.log returns the url, but instead of the image name, it pastes undefined a the end:

```
https://[project_identifier].supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/games/undefined
```

The expected outcome would be:

```
https://[project_identifier].supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/games/gameOneGameTile.jpeg
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Based on a response from @dshukertjr on this question, I have included the path to the image in the table, to be able to use the column name to fetch the data. However, nothing has changed.
[image]

Comment: you should specify the folder name in `.getPublicUrl("/game_one/${tile_url}")`

Comment: @mocherfaoui, thank you very much for your comment!

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It returns the same url (appending 'undefined'). Also, if I have to specify the folder, is there a way to do this dynamically as well, since there will be more than one game...?

Again, thank you very much for your input, appreciate your time.

Comment: if you're not using Next.js 13 with app directory then you need to fetch the image inside a `useEffect`, see this [example](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-nextjs#create-an-upload-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to pass to the `getPublicUrl()` function is the path to the image within the bucket for example like this:

```js
  const pathToImage = 'game_one/gameOneGameTile.jpeg'

  const {data:image_url} = supabase.storage.from("games").getPublicUrl(pathToImage);
```

You are passing `tile_url` in your code. If you want to keep it that way, the path to the image needs to be saved in your `product` table under `tile_url` column for each row to be able to display an image.

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I am trying this, by placing the url for each image in the cell for each row, but it still appends "undefined" to the url when I log it. Nothing happens in the frontend (no images are shown)
I am updating the question as well, to show this option.

Comment: @nelakay Thanks for updating the question and adding the updated screenshot of your table. What you have in the `tile_url` column is the cause. You want to have the path to the image, and not the url. You want to have literally `game_one/gameOneGameTile.jpeg` in there, and not anything that starts with `https://your_supabase_url...`.

Answer (score 0):

For working with private storages, I had to create a signed url that I could use as an image src. There aren't a lot of good alternatives unfortunately, as there isn't a way to pass in the authorizer to an image src.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is top of Google for this question and keywords and for rookies like me, here is a complete process on how you can upload and display image files in supabase buckets

1. Once you have authenticated a user with supabase, you need 3 things to upload an image to a bucket:

   1. the file
   2. a bucket name
   3. a file path
2. When you upload that image you **need to store the file path** in your DB. The file path is how you reference the image later to delete, edit etc.
3. To display the image, you use that store file path to get a publicUrl to the image which you can use to display it. You can't (well shouldn't) just use your project name, and bucket name, and file path to directly construct a URL. There might be policies that prevent access, or supabase could change their file structure. Using the publicUrl function means the image url will always work, and won't randomly break in the future.
4. The getPublicUrl function requires two things, bucket name, and file path

### Details

File paths consist of the folder structure, and the name of the file. **File paths are not URLs.**

A file path could be something like

```
filePath =  images/45.png
```

`images` is the folder I want to put the file in. `45.png` is the name of the file.

So an upload function could look like this:

```
const handleUpload = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); //stop form from reloading page  
    
    const file = event.target.files[0]; //get the file from the file picker
    if (!file) return;
    const fileExt = file.name.split('.').pop(); //get the file type
    const fileName = `${Math.random()}.${fileExt}`; //create a name
    const filePath = `images/${fileName}`; //create the file path

    try {
        let { error } = await supabase.storage
            .from(bucketName)
            .upload(filePath, file);

        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        console.log('File uploaded successfully: ', filePath);
        //this is where you would store the filePath in your DB
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading the file', error);
    } finally {
        getFilePath(filePath); //use the filePath to get the publicUrl
    }
};
```

Then the function to get the public URL, what you will actually use to put the image on your page could look like this:

```
async function getFilePath(filePath) {
    const { data, urlError } = await supabase
        .storage
        .from(bucketName)
        .getPublicUrl(filePath)

    if (urlError) {
        throw urlError;
    }
    console.log('got public url', data)
    setImageUrl(data.publicUrl); //make sure to pull the URL out of the object
}
```